# C fileIO not as expected

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I am trying to do simple writing and reading of a binary file in c and I'm running into difficulties. Here is my code as stripped down as I could make it:

```
typedef struct car_struct{
    char* make;
    char* model;
    short year;
    long price;
    int uniqueID;
}Car;

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("filename", "wb+");

    Car car = {"s","s",1,1,1};
    fwrite(&car, sizeof(Car), 1, fp);

    rewind(fp);
    Car* c;

    fread(c,sizeof(Car),1,fp);


    printf("%d \n",c->price);
}
```

I thought the code would write a struct into the file, then subsequently read it, and print out one of its fields. The actual result, however, is the program terminating with nothing printed out at all. It seems like undefined behavior has crept in somewhere, but I am not sure where. What is the problem with the code?

Comment: You are attempting to read into a memory area which has not been allocated.  I'm surprised you aren't getting a segfault.  You must be conveniently getting a pointer value in your program space, which is going to get you some crazy undefined program corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the line `Car* c;` You created a pointer that points to some random address. You can define the size of the memory you want `c` to hold using `malloc(sizeof(Car))`

Answer (score 1):

You are just writing out pointer values for the strings, not the string themselves. Either make the `make` and `model` something like `char[32]` so they are actually in the struct or write your own read/write routines.

Also don't neglect to check the results of all IO operations - that may give insight into other issues.

Comment: While you are correct, the field I am trying to read is of type long, so I don't think it is possible that is the source of the problem. Please explain if I am wrong